# Safeinput Get Research

Tags: php

Hello I hope explain clear.

This my url

```
 index.php?page_id=chararter&char=Erickson
```

I'm getting Erickson using this code

```
$id= safe_input($_GET['char'],'\_\-');
```

Everything work fine, but when I applied URL FRIENDLY the url traslate to "`chararter/deidad`" then my code just dont take anything at all of this url, how to get character name from url friendly?

thanks.

Comment: Well that is sort of to be exected

Comment: What do you expect us to do about it

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding.  "i applied URL FRIENDLY" is this a library? or maybe some .htaccess URL rewriting? Can you provide steps to reproduce or more code?